# Google Chrome speech to text vs Firewall

Tags: google-chrome, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

When using the Speech to Text APi of Google Chrome (window.speechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition) behind a firewall, the speech to text functionality does not work.
Does anybody know toward which server:ports outbound connections must be allowed in the firewall?